# Outputting mysqli result in CSV file with PHP

Tags: php, csv, mysqli

I'm having a mysqli result set written to a CSV file in PHP using the following code

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM table');
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
foreach ($row as $val) {
fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
```

which, from what I understand, should produce a comma separted line for each row.
However, the contents of the CSV file consists of one long string without linebreaks.
Any idea how to get a linebreak for each row?
Thanks.

```
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: in your current code `$row` is just array for one record. Iterating over it you have a scalar value in `$val`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop until last record and add each record in csv. change your code as:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM table');
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
fputcsv($fp, $row);  
}
fclose($fp);
```